# Power series solution to second order PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, power-series

**Question.** Given a second order PDE
$$u_{tt} = f(x)u_{xx}\label{eq:1}\tag{1}$$
where $f(x)$ is a smooth positive-valued function in its domain. Find a power series solution $u(x,t)$ in $t$ on a small neighborhood of $t=0$ subject to initial conditions
\begin{align*}
u(x,0)&=\phi(x),\\
u_t(x,0)&=\psi(x).
\end{align*}
Also, there is an additional (and ambitious) requirement that the power series solution $u(x,t)$ is not simply expressed by determining its coefficients under certain recurrence relations.

---

Here the uniqueness of the power series solution is trivial. If we write
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n\ge 0}c_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!},$$
then our PDE yields a second order recurrence
$$c_{n+2}(x)=f(x)\frac{d^2c_n(x)}{dx^2}.\label{eq:2}\tag{2}$$
Combining with the initial conditions, all coefficients are uniquely determined.

**However**, the motivation of this question comes from the recurrence \eqref{eq:2} arising from some problems in combinatorics. In those problems, I have a family of functions (not necessarily polynomials!) subject to recurrence relations such as \eqref{eq:2}. Then, the exponential generating function of these functions can be defined and finally I am led to a second order PDE like \eqref{eq:1}. So, the above also explains why the requirement in the question is added --- characterizing the recurrence for the coefficients of $t^n$ in the solution $u(x,t)$ does nothing but brings me back to the origin.